# Azure Portal doesn't show details

Tags: angular, azure, azure-application-insights

Unable to see appropriate logs in Azure Portal even though the integration was done.

have followed instructions given in 
https://louiseclark.tech/azure-application-insights/adding-application-insights-angular

Need to see all the details in Azure Portal like the username, current url, name. Do I need to pass all the parameters myself or will the application insights capture it on its own. Kindly help.

```
in app-insights-service
        constructor(private router: Router) {
            if (!AppInsights.config) { 
                AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(this.config);
            }
        }

        logPageView(name: string, url?: string, properties?: any, measurements?: any, duration?: number) {
            AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, properties, measurements, duration);
        }


in app.component.ts, in constructor, I invoked these by
        this.appInsightsService.logPageView('Sequation-UI-PageView');
```

Do I need to pass the parameters like this or will Application Insight capture the details by itself.

Answer (score 1):

As per this [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#trackpageview), the url / name should have a default value, see the screenshot below for details. For others' properties, you should manually add them to the properties parameter in the method.

[image]

Comment: Yes. It works for some APIs and din't work some. For setAuthenticatedUserContext(userName) it doesn't work. I tried passing parameters with aunthenticated users, still it din't work

Comment: I moved this function setAuthenticatedUserContext(userName) from app.component.ts in to the service that fires soon after a successful login, it worked for me.

Comment: How to write custom event names/types in Azure Application Insight?

Comment: @Ramya, you can use [trackEvent](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#trackevent) method.

Comment: I did call the method and passed 1 parameter, now the value that I passed as parameter is what I see on the portal under Event Name and I want to change that.

Comment: @Ramya, you want to change that? please correct me if I misunderstand you, you want to pass a new value instead of the old one? if it's the case, you can just pass a new value :)

Comment: @Ramya, do you still have issues?

Comment: Issue has been resolved. Since I was working with Angular and Application Insights, I used hostListener and fetched the events and passed that a s a parameter for trackEvent(). So now I get the active event name in the azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

All the custom methods for Azure Application Insights works but depends on how and where you invoke these methods. 
For page name I fetched it from the URL and invoked trackPageView() in app.component.ts and passed the first parameter from the URL.

For username, I fetched the login name after the user logs in and invoke the appInsight method setAuthenticatedUserContext in the sigin service and paased the username as the parameter.

For events, I fetched the events using angular hostListener and called appInsight method trackEvent() and passed the event fetched as parameter.

This worked for me.